# how to find duplicate rows in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I feel weeks ago I asked a question about counting identical rows in one dataset. This is an answer I received:

```
select count(*), a_dttm, b_dttm, c_dttm 
from data 
group by a_ddtm, b_dttm, c_dttm;
```

I know that there are duplicates in this other dataset and they're messing up my count. As of right now, I know what id is used multiple times, but it doesn't necessarily mean it that those rows are duplicated.

```
select id, count(*) as count
from (
select *
from data
where date >= '2016-01-01' and date <= '2016-12-31'
) as a
group by id
having count(*) >= 2
order by count desc
```

My question is how can I select all the rows that are **completely** identical in my dataset? Would I write a subquery for each column or select * ?

Answer (score 0):

If I were to find a solution in finding duplicate values on a script, i do a count(*) and do a group by function to count the number of duplicates. which is the answer you got previously.

To answer your question, I would suggest to add the 'date' on your group by and select as it is an indicator for "uniqueness" for the field that you need to use.

I simply would find or create a "Primary Index" to make sure that all the data used is unique.

however, if you dont want to mess your numbers, I normally use DISTINCT as an easy way remove the duplicates on that table. see reference below:
http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-select-distinct/